# Eclipse Debugger in version 2018-12 (4.10.0) not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to debug my application using eclipse but I have some other named attribute inside map in debug mode

I have also attached the screenshot below of my Eclipse running in debug mode:

This is my debug

[image: mydebugApp]

This is what I want to get

[image: otherdebugApp]

Actually what I want to know is the table and linked node structure and value inside **HashMap**

Comment: What do you mean ? The view is not shown ? (did you try to open it : Window->Show View->Variable ?)  The variable map is not shown (as on your screenshot) ? it's because at that point its not created yet

Comment: @greg-449 I have attached the screenshot to illustrate my problem since I use step over but I am getting not what I wanted I have updated my question of what I am want....each index has key and value....and key has hashcode and value

Comment: @greg-449 Can you help I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top screen shot, you have `Show Logical Structure` toggle enabled. Find it at the top of the `Variables` view, the icon shows an arrow pointing to the right at a little hierarchical structure.
In the popup menu that you get when you right click on items in the `Variables` view, you can even define your own logical structures (e.g. for java.util.Map it is predefined as return entrySet().toArray();)